# How can I copy data from one MySQL server to another based on a SELECT statement (then delete the data from the original)?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, php

I have a very large log table from which I want to copy rows, putting them into the same table structure on a new server.  I don't want to copy everything, only old rows, so that the table on the main server stays small-ish.  So I have to SELECT the data I want and only move (and delete) that.

Keep in mind that there is a *lot* of data, and I don't want to copy it all with a `mysqldump` if I don't need to, especially if it's going to lock the table while it's being copied.

The best I've come up with is a PHP script, which I will post as a tentative answer, although I'm certain it's not the best option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [pt-archiver](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-archiver.html), part of the Percona Toolkit. The tool can purge rows from a table; write rows from a table to file; purge rows from a table while copying them to another table (possibly another server)...

It does so in chunks, so like 1,000 rows at a time, so that there is no high load on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Please bear with me as I am kind of sluggish with PHP

```
//Connect to both databases, which are set up the same
$localDB = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, "db"); 
$remoteDB = new mysqli("remotehost.com", $username, $password, "db");
$maxDate = //some timestamp in the past

//Set up query to get the data
$getQuery = "SELECT message FROM `log` WHERE timestamp < ?";
$getStmt = $remoteDB->prepare($getQuery);
$getStmt->bind_param('i',$maxDate);
$getStmt->execute();
$getStmt->bind_result($message);

//Set up query to insert the data 20 at a time
$commitCount = 0;
$commitLimit = 20;
$putQueryPrefix = "INSERT INTO `log` (message) VALUES ";
$putQuerySuffix = "";
$comma = "";

//Read many rows and insert them in bulk
while ($getStmt->fetch()) {
  $putQuerySuffix .= "$comma('$message')";
  $comma = ",";
  $commitCount++;
  if ( $commitCount == $commitLimit ) {
    $putQuery = $putQueryPrefix . $putQuerySuffix;
    $putStmt = $localDB->prepare($putQuery);
    $putStmt->execute();
    $commitCount = 0;
    $putQuerySuffix = "";
    $comma = "";
  }
}
if ( $commitCount > 0 ) {
  $putQuery = $putQueryPrefix . $putQuerySuffix;
  $putStmt = $localDB->prepare($putQuery);
  $putStmt->execute();
}

//And we're done
$getStmt->close();
$putStmt->close();

//Now delete it from the old server
$result = $remoteDB->query("DELETE FROM `log` WHERE timestamp < $maxDate");
$result->free();

$remoteDB->close();
$localDB->close();
```

The general idea is this: mysqldump preps multiple rows for a single INSERT statement. This is known as an extended INSERT. My example shows how to create a group of 20 rows to perform such an INSERT. If you want to increase `$commitLimit` to something greater than 20, you may have to increase [**max_allowed_packet**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) on the Remote Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Connect to both databases, which are set up the same
$localDB = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, "db"); 
$remoteDB = new mysqli("remotehost.com", $username, $password, "db");
$maxDate = //some timestamp in the past

//Set up query to get the data
$getQuery = "SELECT message FROM `log` WHERE timestamp < ?";
$getStmt = $remoteDB->prepare($getQuery);
$getStmt->bind_param('i',$maxDate);
$getStmt->execute();
$getStmt->bind_result($message);

//Set up query to insert the data
$putQuery = "INSERT INTO `log` (message) VALUES (?)";
$putStmt = $localDB->prepare($putQuery);
$putStmt->bind_param('s',$message);

//Read each row and insert it
while ($getStmt->fetch()) {
  $putStmt->execute();
  $putStmt->fetch();
}

//And we're done
$getStmt->close();
$putStmt->close();

//Now delete it from the old server
$result = $remoteDB->query("DELETE FROM `log` WHERE timestamp < $maxDate");
$result->free();

$remoteDB->close();
$localDB->close();
```